# Having trouble with the webpack module resolution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have a global npm module installed, let's call it `abc-cli`. Now I have a react `app` that runs with this command: `abc-cli run`.

What `abc-cli` basically does is gets the components in the `app` and compiles and runs it with its source.

Now I want to publish this `app` as a separate npm module. So I am using the Webpack to generate the bundle. While resolving modules, webpack is unable to resolve the modules that are a part of the `abc-cli`. That is obvious, webpack has no idea what `abc-cli` is.

So my question is how do I make sure that webpack resolves the modules dependencies? Is there any way I can make the webpack run/compile the `abc-cli` while bundling.

Or the worst case could be how to suppress the module resolution warning or ignore those modules. Because I know that its going to be present.

Example:

In my `app`, I have an import statement as

```
import SomeComponent from '@abc/components';
```

Now while bundling, the webpack won't resolve this module:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@abc/components' in '/home/shishir/app/src/shared/visualizations'
```

It would be great help if I could get around this.

My webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              'es2015',
              'react',
              'stage-2'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'commonjs react'
  }
};
```

I tried the [null-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/null-loader):

```
{
        test: require.resolve("@abc/components"),
        use: 'null-loader'
}
```

but it didnt help.

Comment: what about using [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) just like you're using it for react? If I understand correctly, it will be present

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These're two ways to inform webpack of extra location to look for a module.

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    // 1. add extra `node_modules` directory to search path
    modules: ['node_modules', '/abs_path/to/global/node_modules'],
    // 2. use alias to explicitly map a module name to its exact location
    alias: {
      '@abc': '/abs_path/to/global/node_modules/@abc'
    }
  }
};
```

For your use case, if you only has `@abc` module sitting outside the conventional local `node_modules` directory, I'd recommend you use `resolve.alias`.

Source: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules.

Comment: I was able to add alias and it worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing an import like this:

```
import SomeComponent from '@abc/components';
```

You are telling Webpack to import a module named `@abc/components` from its "resolve root". This resolve root is normally *'node_modules'*. (Imagine if `@abc/components` was an npm package, that'd work fine.)

As you obtained this library from a different source via your command line tool, you will have these dependencies at a different location. Webpack won't magically recognize these, but you have a few simple options:

1. Make `abc-cli` copy the `abc`'s component files to `app`'s `node_modules/@abc`.
2. Create a symlink in `app`'s `node_modules` called `@abc` that points to abc's folder. Webpack [traverses symlinks by default](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve#resolvesymlinks) and this spares you the time to copy the files each time. Slightly better solution IMO, especially if `abc` changes more than once in a while.
3. Tell webpack to also search for modules in `@abc`'s folder, not just `node_modules`. You can do that using [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve#resolvemodules) just like Ngô Hùng Phúc showed in his answer. Be a little careful though, as you are importing the modules like `@abc/components` you have to point webpack to the directory **one level above** `@abc`, and of course this requires abc's component directory to be called `@abc`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let webpack know what is your location of that module.
My project have structure like this

[image]

Ex: I want to import some file in Helper folder I will need to do this

```
import {isDomExist} from "Helper/Util";
```

Because below code do this for me

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve('./React/js/App'),
        path.resolve('./React/js/App/Modules/Client'),
        path.resolve('./React/js/App/Modules/Adnmin'),
        path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]
},
```

You can see that I tell webpack to resolve the path come from ./React/js/App.

So Helper folder is live inside App folder webpack will know where to look for.

Below is my full source code for your ref [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

Please let me know if this is the fix for you